# How can I provoke multiple calls to Finalize?

Tags: ada, finalize

In a recent [AdaCore Gem](http://www.adacore.com/2011/01/17/gem-97-reference-counting-in-ada-part-1/) there's a statement

> The implementation of Finalize is slightly more complicated: the Ada reference manual indicates that a Finalize procedure should always be idempotent. An Ada compiler is free to call Finalize multiple times on the same object, in particular when exceptions occur.

I need to test a privately controlled type,

```
   type T is private;
private
   type T is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with ...
```

I can change the source to make the type visibly controlled

```
   type T is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with private;
```

and then just call `Finalize (My_T);` (or even `My_T.Finalize`?); but is there any way I can cause multiple finalizations without this change to the software-under-test?

Comment: Whoa. Got me stumped on that one. Best I can think of would be to figure out what (if any) conditions cause your compiler to pull that multi-finalize trick, and try to induce it. That wouldn't make for a portable test though.

Comment: Perhaps I just need to accept that it has to be visibly controlled. Better to make it testable even if it adds some otherwise-unneeded scaffolding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of testing, I use a child package.  It allows to tests the private part.
Assuming your package is:

```
package A is
   type T is private;
private
   type T is new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with ...
end A;
```

I would test with something like:

```
package body A.Test is
   procedure Test_Finalize is
       My_T : T;
   begin
       My_T.Finalize;
   end Test_Finalize;
end A.Test;
```

Comment: I too have found special child packages (sometimes called "bastard children") quite useful for unit tests, due to their ability to get at the internals of a package from the outside.

Comment: I knew that! Really! Thanks very much, just the job.